# MySQL: shorten a column with SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql

I Am trying to do this:

```
update student 
set student_name=SUBSTRING(student_name, 0, 8)
where student_name like 'MAX%';
```

So, my intent is to update the column with first 8 chars of the original content.

But the `student_name` column is getting set to empty value.

Why is this happening? can someone help me fix this

Answer (score 5):

Before update anything, do select with similar request.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select SUBSTRING('123456',1,2 ), SUBSTRING('123456',0,2 ); 
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('123456',1,2 ) | SUBSTRING('123456',0,2 ) |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 12                       |                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Invalid or negative first number in substring resulting empty string.

Comment: Ah! should have looked at the docs. SQL starts with 1!

Comment: Looking in the doc is a nice idea, but more important is always do select with the same where and the exact update string. Recover messed up data is a pain.

Comment: that's wise! thank you!